# NuxtJS and Github User Pages

Tags: github-pages, github-actions, nuxtjs

Github has two kind of pages:

- User
- Projects

I have a User page. So I want to publish from the `master` branch. I want to use NuxtJS. NuxtJS generates a CI file when you install it. Following https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/deployment/github-pages I also set up a CD file whereas I went for npm instead of yarn.

So I have
ci.yml

```
name: ci

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - master
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
      - master

jobs:
  ci:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}

    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: [ubuntu-latest]
        node: [14]

    steps:
      - name: Checkout 
        uses: actions/checkout@master

      - name: Setup node env 
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2.1.2
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node }}
          check-latest: true

      - name: Cache node_modules 
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: ~/.npm
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-node-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-node-

      - name: Install dependencies ‍
        run: npm ci

      - name: Run linter 
        run: npm run lint
```

cd.yml

```
name: cd

on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:
  cd:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}

    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: [ubuntu-latest]
        node: [14]

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@master

      - name: Setup node env
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2.1.2
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node }}

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm ci

      - name: Generate
        run: npm run generate

      - name: Deploy
        uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          publish_dir: ./dist
```

Now if I understood it correctly: Those actions will generate and create the static sites i.e. the `dist` directory. In the cd.yml file we then set:

- name: Deploy
  uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3
  with:
  github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
  publish_dir: ./dist

So everything seems okay but we did use `peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3` which seems to create a `gh_pages` branch, so it seems my cd.yml file might be wrong?

If I go to my user github page I just see the readme.md displayed. What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Specify the `publish_branch` parameter for the `actions-gh-pages` action (see [docs](https://github.com/peaceiris/actions-gh-pages#%EF%B8%8F-set-another-github-pages-branch-publish_branch)):

```
      - name: Deploy
        uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          publish_dir: ./dist
          # new
          publish_branch: master
```